# Who do I pass the value of an input element to ngClick

Tags: angularjs

Who do I pass the value of an number input element to `ngClick` in the example below?

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  {{ item.name }}
  <input type="number">
  <button type="button" ng-click="something(item, valueOfInputElement)>click</button>
</div>
```

Adding `ng-model="item.number"` to the input element works but this seems like overkill to just get the value of an input element.

Comment: It is not an overkill. It is the right way to do it in angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `ng-model` to the `input` *is* the way to do this.  It is not overkill.  This is the documented way to handle input data in Angular.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  {{ item.name }}
  <input type="number" ng-model="item.myNumber">
  <button type="button" ng-click="something(item)>click</button>
</div>
```

In the above example, `ng-model` is bound to `item.myNumber`.  Binding inside each `item` in the `ng-repeat` will make sure that you are changing each `item` individually.  Then, you can pass only `item` in the `ng-click` (because `myNumber` is now a property of `item`).